# SQL Sever, ¿Como obtener la cantidad de días de una columna con fechas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

vengo buscando todas las soluciones posibles para este problema pero sin exito alguna, de hecho estoy tratando de obtener la cantidad de días que hay entre estas fechas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo entendido que existen muchas soluciones cuando estas fechas se encuentran en dos columnas, para simple añadir la función DATEPART, pero en este caso solo tengo una columna. Por otro lado se iran añadiendo fechas por lo que busco una solucion "dinamica" por asi decirlo.

**En este caso el resultado seria 6**
*Disculpen el error*

Ante todo gracias.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88670/discussion-on-question-by-cristopher-sql-sever-como-obtener-la-cantidad-de-dia).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es obtener los días desde una *fecha1* hasta una *fecha2*, ***incluyendo fines de semana y contando el día de inicio*** podrías aplicar esto

```
SELECT 
   DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(FECHA), MAX(FECHA)) + 1
FROM TABLA
```

Ahora bien, como no queda claro si necesitas o no omitir los fines de semana te dejo la respuesta de igual manera que realiza ese cálculo

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(DD, MIN('2019-01-10'), MAX('2019-01-16')) + 1) + 
CASE WHEN 
   DATEPART(DW, MIN('2019-01-10')) = 7 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END - 
(DATEDIFF(WK, MIN('2019-01-10'), MAX('2019-01-16')) * 2) -
CASE WHEN 
   DATEPART(DW, MIN('2019-01-10')) = 1 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN 
   DATEPART(DW, MAX('2019-01-16')) = 1 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Esto último se basa en la respuesta que se encuentra **[aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server)**

Nos comentas :)

Comment: La respuesta esta bien, no la borres.. pero parece que OP tiene los tantos un poco confundidos...

Comment: Iba a editarla, pero me causa confusión también.. en el caso que necesite la fecha de inicio bastaría con agregarle un +1... eso entendí por lo menos =/.. veamos que pasa

Comment: acorde a lo que pregunta el OP esta correcta, ahora que el OP este planteando una solución no adecuada a su problema de fondo ese es otro problema yo le doy mi voto

Comment: uhmmm, ahora que mencionó el asunto de que no se ingresarán los fines de semana y que por lo tanto no se deben considerar, creo que esta respuesta no es la correcta

Comment: Muchas gracias @PauloUrbanoRivera, de ante mano te lo agradezco. Y a todos por contribuir en mi problema, gracias a todos. Un saludo

Comment: @Cristopher ademas de las gracias, recuerda aceptar la respuesta si esta soluciono tu problema. Igual, te recomiendo que leas mi ultimo comentario en la pregunta, ya que es dudoso que esto sea lo que realmente necesitas.

Comment: Me sumo al comentario de @gbianchi... antes de aceptar la respuesta analiza muy bien si es lo que realmente necesitas y visualiza todos los escenarios posibles para evitar futuras inconsistencias en tus datos

Comment: Ponele un +1 al datediff para que sume el borde (un dia completo mas) y listo.. no entiendo lo que pide OP realmente.

Comment: Tal vez esto les sirva a otros compañeros, no por eso tendria que decir que esta mal. Como mencione cualquier respuesta es agradecida.

Comment: no @Cristopher, asi no funciona el sitio, mira por favor el [tour]. En el sitio hay una pregunta y una o mas respuestas que responden la pregunta, no que responden cualquier cosa. Aceptar respuestas es la forma de agradecerlas. Votarlas positiva o negativamente es la forma de demostrar que tan buena es la misma. Lee todo lo que te escribimos por favor, hace el [tour] que es muy importante, y lee tambien [ask]

Comment: Esta bien gbianchi tendre en cuenta tus palabras. Acabo de probar esta respuesta y me resulto factible, espero que a varios usuarios le ayude. Gracias @PauloUrbanoRivera y todos.

Comment: Me alegro @Cristopher... debes aceptar la respuesta como correcta para cerrar la misma :)